# Getting values from array that matches a regular expression using lodash

Tags: javascript, json, regex, lodash

My json array:

```
[{"id":"7","name":"hello"},{"id":"7","name":"shan"},{"id":"7","name":"john"}
{"id":"7","name":"hello"}]
```

I want to get a new array that matches a regular expression on `name` starting with a letter.

I am using [regexp](https://lodash.com/docs#isRegExp) but i don't know how to implement it.

Here is my code:

```
var newitem=_.filter(result,item=>item.name='hello');
 console.log(newitem);
```

But it returns with only strict match of `name`.

Please help me to modify the above so that the result is a new array as described.

**Expected output**

when a usertype letter `h` it shows only the row

```
{"id":"7","name":"hello"}
```

Comment: Filter elements whose `name` start with **any letter**?

Comment: Note that `item.name='hello'` will assign the string value. You need to use `==` or `===`.

Comment: Shouldn't expected output contain two objects as there are two objects whose `name` starts with `h`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To check if the `name` starts with a string, you can use `RegExp#test` with regex.

```
var newItem = _.filter(result, obj => /^[a-zA-Z]/.test(obj.name));
```

The regex `^[a-zA-Z]` will check if the name starts with alphabet.

```js
var arr = [{
    "id": "7",
    "name": "hello"
}, {
    "id": "7",
    "name": "shan"
}, {
    "id": "7",
    "name": "jhon"
}, {
    "id": "7",
    "name": "hello"
}, {
    id: 10,
    name: '$haun'
}];

var newItem = _.filter(arr, obj => /^[a-zA-Z]/.test(obj.name));
console.log(newItem);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.com/libraries/lodash.js/"></script>
```

Same code can be written using `Array#filter`.

```
arr.filter(obj => /^[a-zA-Z]/.test(obj.name));
```

```js
var arr = [{
    "id": "7",
    "name": "hello"
}, {
    "id": "7",
    "name": "*shan"
}, {
    "id": "7",
    "name": "jhon"
}, {
    "id": "7",
    "name": "hello"
}, {
    id: 10,
    name: '$haun'
}];

var newItem = arr.filter(obj => /^[a-zA-Z]/.test(obj.name));
console.log(newItem);
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(newItem, 0, 4) + '</pre>';
```

---

**Update:**

> when a usertype letter h it shows only the row

You can use

```
_.filter(result, obj => /^h/.test(obj.name));
```

Use `i`-case insensitive flag to match the alphabet irrespective of the case. That'll match both `h` and `H`.

Comment: But it will returns all the rows

Comment: @BlessanKurien You said _I want to get a new array that matches a regular expression on name starting with a letter._ right. What is expected output?

Comment: @BlessanKurien Do you want to filter the objects whose name starts with `h`, then you just need to use `/^h/` regex. Use `i` flag to match case-insensitively i.e. both `h` and `H`.

Comment: Updated my question with expected output

Comment: I am asking regular expression in lodash library  https://lodash.com/docs#isRegExp

Comment: @BlessanKurien Check update at the bottom of the answer. And the expected output should `[{"id":"7","name":"hello"}, {"id":"7","name":"hello"}]` as their `name` starts with `h`.

Comment: @BlessanKurien You don't need `isRegExp`, it _Checks if value is classified as a RegExp object._. You don't want to check if the value of `name` is regex.

Comment: ok one more question instead of  letter `h` i want to place variable

Comment: @BlessanKurien You need `RegExp` constructor. Check [How do you pass a variable to a Regular Expression JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-pass-a-variable-to-a-regular-expression-javascript)

Comment: bcz when user type   a keyword it is assigned to a variable and returns the rows based on that match

Comment: I am using this way `'/^'+keyword+'/'.test(item.name)` but it gives an error `"/".test is not a function`

Comment: @BlessanKurien Use `new RegExp("^" + keyword).test(...`

Comment: @BlessanKurien No, you didn't mention that the keyword is dynamic.

Comment: I've tried this  `new RegExp("/^"+keyword+"/").test(item.name)` but returns null result

Comment: @BlessanKurien READ MY LAST [COMMENT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35497598/getting-values-from-array-that-matches-a-regular-expression-using-loadash#comment58688101_35497671). YOU DON"T NEED `/`.

Answer (score 0):

regex ('^h.') should work on this. To get row with name h.